# How to implement Metamask using React componet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, ethereum, metamask

## What I want to do

I'm trying to use Next.js to connect to Metamask in a local environment to get the addresses and balances of accounts.

So first, I am trying to implement a simple UI where I can place a "wallet button" to connect to Metamask and get Accounts object by pressing it.

## My Code

Layout.jsx mounted on index.jsx, which is implemented by ConnectWallet.jsx and ConnectMetamaskButton.jsx as shown below,

`Layout.jsx`

```
import React from "react";
import ConnectWallet from "./ConnectWallet";


export default function Layout({ children }) {
    return (
        <>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/js/all.min.js"></script>
            <header className="text-gray-100 bg-gray-900 body-font shadow w-full">
                <div className="container mx-auto flex flex-wrap p-5 flex-col md:flex-row items-center">
                    <nav className="flex lg:w-2/5 flex-wrap items-center text-base md:ml-auto">
                        <a className="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900 cursor-pointer border-b border-transparent hover:border-indigo-600">Home</a>
                    </nav>
                    <a
                        className="flex order-first lg:order-none lg:w-1/5 title-font font-medium items-center lg:items-center lg:justify-center mb-4 md:mb-0">
                        <span className="ml-3 text-xl">L2 DEX HUB</span>
                    </a>
                    <div className="lg:w-2/5 inline-flex lg:justify-end ml-5 lg:ml-0">
                        <ConnectWallet />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </>
    )
}
```

`ConnectWallet.jsx`

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { ethers } from 'ethers';

export default function ConnectWallet(props) {
    const [Accounts, setAccounts] = useState("connect");
    console.log(Accounts);

    async function ConnectMetamask() {
        console.log("2", Accounts);

        try {
            const newAccounts = await ethereum.request({
                method: 'eth_requestAccounts',
            })

            let accounts = newAccounts;
            setAccounts({ accounts })
            console.log(accounts);
            console.log("3", Accounts);


            const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
            console.log(provider);

            const signer = provider.getSigner(0);
            console.log(signer);

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => { ConnectMetamask }}>wallet</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

`ConnectMetamaskButton`

```
export default function ConnectMetamaskButton(props) {
    return (
        <button className="btn-blue" onClick={() => props.onClick()}>
            address:{props.Accounts}
        </button>
    );
}
```

and we are trying to retrieve the Accounts object by prop and state. This is implemented by ConnectWallet.jsx and ConnectMetamaskButton.jsx as follows.

Incidentally, in this implementation, the goal is to have the "wallet button" display the address name.
However, as far as I can tell from the console, the process after onClick in ConnectWallet.jsx is not working.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this bug?

Comment: You're not actually calling `ConnectMetamask` function in the `onClick` callback in `ConnectWallet`. Shouldn't it be `() => { ConnectMetamask(); }`?

Comment: oh,yes. It's My fault. thank you sir, This problem peacefully resoleved.